# How to write a single minimatch glob that matches all js files not in a directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, glob, minimatch

I have a situation where I need a single glob pattern (that uses [`minimatch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minimatch)) to match all JavaScript files which are not in a certain directory. Unfortunately, I'm using another tool that doesn't expose any options (like an `ignore` glob), so it has to be a single glob to do the job.

[Here's what I have so far](http://www.globtester.com/#p=eJzT0tJX1EjJTy7W1NfSyyoGABzeBAM%3D&r=eJyzScksU0jOSSwutlXKTSxJzlCyS8lPLtZPy8%2FXL8nIzEvXyyq20QcqsrNBUglVhFsB1KjknMzUvBJ9okxEVotPnU1SkR1OC4uLkglYhKSQoCKQW3QJG4mkkJQQIcpkdPWoagF%2BFpyo&)

[image: screenshot of globtester]

Example input (it should *not* match the top, but it *should* match the bottom):

```
docs/foo/thing.js
docs/thing.js
client/docs/foo/thing.js
client/docs/thing.js

src/foo/thing.js
src/thing.js
docs-src/foo/thing.js
docs-src/thing.js
client/docs-src/foo/thing.js
client/docs-src/thing.js
```

And here's what I have for the glob pattern so far:

```
**/!(docs)/*.js
```

With that I'm matching `docs/foo/thing.js` and `client/docs/foo/thing.js` and not matching `docs-src/thing.js` or `client/docs-src/thing.js`. If I switch my glob to `**/!(docs)/**/*.js` then I can match `client/docs-src/thing.js`, but I also match `client/docs/thing.js`.

I'm not certain this is possible so I may need to find another solution for my problem :-/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you may be running into a limitation of minimatch (or any implementation of fnmatch(3)) and globstar.  It's perhaps worth noting that no C implementation of fnmatch that I'm aware of actually *does* implement globstar, but since fnmatch impls (including minimatch) serve the interests of their globbers, this may vary.

The glob that you think should work actually does work, when used as a glob.

```
$ find . -type f
./docs/foo/thing.js
./docs/thing.js
./docs/nope.txt
./docs-src/foo/thing.js
./docs-src/thing.js
./x.sh
./client/docs/foo/thing.js
./client/docs/thing.js
./client/docs/nope.txt
./client/docs-src/foo/thing.js
./client/docs-src/thing.js
./client/docs-src/nope.txt
./client/nope.txt
./src/foo/thing.js
./src/thing.js

$ for i in ./!(docs)/**/*.js; do echo $i; done
./client/docs-src/foo/thing.js
./client/docs-src/thing.js
./client/docs/foo/thing.js
./client/docs/thing.js
./docs-src/foo/thing.js
./docs-src/thing.js
./src/foo/thing.js
./src/thing.js

$ node -p 'require("glob").sync("./!(docs)/**/*.js")'
[ './client/docs-src/foo/thing.js',
  './client/docs-src/thing.js',
  './client/docs/foo/thing.js',
  './client/docs/thing.js',
  './docs-src/foo/thing.js',
  './docs-src/thing.js',
  './src/foo/thing.js',
  './src/thing.js' ]
```

EDIT: Oh, I see, you want to only match things at any folder depth that do not have *any* `docs` path parts *anywhere* in the path.  No, that is not possible to do in a way that supports arbitrary depth, as a glob or a minimatch pattern.  You'll have to use excludes, or construct a glob that looks like: `{!(docs),!(docs)/!(docs),!(docs)/!(docs)/!(docs),!(docs)/!(docs)/!(docs)/!(docs)}/*.js`

Otherwise, a path like `x/docs/y/z.js` will match against `**/!(docs)/**/*.js` by saying that the first `**` matches nothing, the `!(docs)` matches against `x`, the next `**` matches against `docs/y` and then `*.js` matches against `z.js`.

Comment: "This is not possible" is an acceptable answer. I'll figure out something else. Thank you Isaacs!

Comment: I wonder why includes (?) work fine with arbitrary depth though, whereas excludes (!) don't.

Answer (score 1):

I got closer, with the following:

```
**/?(docs*[a-zA-Z0-9]|!(docs))/*.js
```

[globtester](http://www.globtester.com/#p=eJzT0tK310jJTy7Wik7UrXLUjTLQtYytUQQLaWrqa%2BllFQMAsKwKAA%3D%3D&r=eJyV0E0KgCAQBeCrhPsa2purLmLTj4ZpNNL5K4iQwLT9994bhvd6L9BIooYt0qNiondIMDoHXmk7VTNxOJHggbxRHNxVaPRgPWQ1hvbL8W4T0UHaMDEUwCS6bimzKx%2F95y359e%2FQn0ANPlO2IM2q5KMPgoS%2FrQ%3D%3D&)

Still trying to get it to work for arbitrary depth.